# Method to get only procedures from an oracle database using Java

Tags: java, resultset, procedure, database-metadata

I need to get only the procedures using java DatabaseMetaData but this method returns also the functions' names.

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd=con.getMetaData();
ResultSet result = dbmd.getProcedures(null, Ousername, null);
```

Comment: I have the same question.

Comment: This may behave differently depending on the specific DBMS driver. Which one are you using, @gtzinos and @SteveL?

Comment: @ericbn ,we are both using oracle but the same happens in postgresql too.

Comment: @gtzinos Two questions: 2) Do you only need this on an Oracle Database? 2) Do you have to use `DatabaseMetaData` ?

Comment: @StefanFerstl Yes only using Database metadata

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happens because procedures and functions are basically the same in Oracle.

There is a column `PROCEDURE_TYPE` of the type `short` that will show the kind of procedure:

- `1` means there is no result, so it is a procedure.
- `2` means it returns a result, so it is a function.

You can access that column as usual from the `ResultSet`:

```
result.getShort("PROCEDURE_TYPE")
```